# Unable to install Bundle successfully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, bundle

For some reason when I try to install Bundle via Rails, I get an error that renders could not locate gem file. What do I need to do to correct this? These are the following errors:

```
Installing sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2) with native extensions /Users/demetriuford/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Comment: So, what does your `mkmf.log` say? You can probably use `find ~/.rvm -path \*sqlite3-ruby\*/mkmf.log` to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest OS X XCode developer tools installed? http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html

Comment: I have 3.1.3 & I am running it on Leopard. I tried to download the latest version but it says it's only for Snow Leopard....unless im wrong.

Comment: Do you have Sqlite3 installed?

Comment: I figured out what the problem was after hacking away with it. I just needed to specify which version of Sqlite3 to install under my Gemfile.